# Wicket tester not searching WebApplicationPath

Tags: wicket-1.6, wicket-tester

In my first Wicket project (developed in Wicket 6.20 using Eclipse mars and Glassfish 4.1) based on the Quickstart Maven archetype, I am using
`getResourceSettings().getResourceFinders().add(new WebApplicationPath(getServletContext(), "html"));` to separate markup from code.

My homepage works well, but the WicketTester throws an exception `org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Can not determine Markup. Component is not yet connected to a parent. [Page class = ...MyProject.HomePage, id = 0, render count = 1]`

This problem does not seem to be addressed anywhere in the literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of searching, a thorough debugging session lead me to the JavaDoc for *MockServletContext* which explains that it is necessary to supply an absolute path to the root of the application on disk if non-default resource locations are used.

Furthermore, I found that this path can be supplied as a second argument to the constructor of WicketTester.

So, my test Setup() method finishes with :

```
return new WicketTester(new WicketApplication(),"<path to Eclipse workspace>/MyProject/src/main/webapp");
```